# How to use inputs in an if statement in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a code in MATLAB that has the user input two values.  I already have everything written for the input part and I saved the two inputs into two variables: `value1` and `value2`.

What I'm trying to do is use the input values in the matter of:

```
if value1 = 2 
    output_result=10
if value1 = 3 
    output_result=20
```

and so on.

I've been trying to write an `if-elseif` statement but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a [switch](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/switch.html) statement

```
switch value1
   case 2
      result = 10;
   case 3
      result = 20;
    ...
   otherwise
      statements
end
```

Comment: switch value1
   case 1
      result1=345;
   case 2
      result1=3453;
    case 3
        result1=123;
end
switch value2
   case 1
      result2=1445;
   case 2
      result2=2353;
    case 3
        result2=7543;
end
y=[result2 result1]
bar(y)                                                                  when i write like this i get the error:                                      SWITCH expression must be a scalar or string constant.

Comment: @John - That's because `value` is NOT a single value or a string.  It is probably a matrix or vector.  Double check what `value1` is before you continue.

Comment: when i output value1 to the screen to chech it says value1= '1'

Comment: @John - `value1` is a string.  Do this before the switch statement: `value1 = str2num(value1);`

Comment: thanks that worked, however had to use str2double instead of str2num

Comment: @John - Yeah, I just read that `str2num` is deprecated for later versions of MATLAB.  You're probably using a more recent version than what I have here.

Comment: @John - If you have resolved your problem, consider accepting one of our answers.  This can be done by going to the top of any one of our answers, and clicking on the checkmark icon that's at the bottom of the voting up and down arrows, to the left at the top of either post.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use an `if` statement, do this:

```
if value == 1
    result = 10;
elseif value == 2
    result = 20;
elseif
    %// Put more statements
...
elseif
    %// Put even MOAR statements
...
...
else
   %// Default case - optional
end
```

However, the `switch` statement as per @kkuilla is more elegant.  Also note that the `else` statement is optional.  You'd only put this in if everything else fails and want to use a default case.

Comment: Man, you are very prolific. Well done... :-) [Matlab Top Users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/topusers)

Comment: @kkuilla - Haha thanks :)  Luis Mendo and Divakar alternated back and forth for a while for the top spot.  I'm surprised I'm at the top this time!